# How to order background images?

Tags: html, css

There are two images in HTML markup: '.map-teaser-container' and '.wave'. In other words map-teaser comes first and after it goes wave.
The problem is that on a page they are rendered contra versa: first comes wave and then map-teaser.
How is it possible? How to fix it?
https://jsfiddle.net/rinatoptimus/byhqkw0q/

```
.map-teaser-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('http://www.metsawood.com/PublishingImages/PlanB/Extension-building/city-above-the-city-architects-competition-plan-b.jpg?RenditionID=28') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.wave {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 323px;
  background: url('https://abc-accelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/abc-smart-cities.jpg') no-repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put an element in front of another (or vice versa) just use the `z-index` property. Apply a higher `z-index` to the element you want in front. For example, for `.map-teaser-container` to be above `.wave` use `z-index: 2;` in `.map-teaser-container` and `z-index: 1;` in `.wave`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt9bo2he/1/)

Comment: Image with green figures should be above and both 2 images should be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Simply flip the order of the `<div>`s in your code.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byhqkw0q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I removed wrapper div with position: relative & added styles to my blocks:

```
  margin-top: -3px;
  //position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;

  max-height: px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: %;
  background-position: center;
```

}